# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I've built a CNN that can classify images from two different classes. However, I keep on getting this error when I try to run classification code:

`AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'`

This is the part of the code that is causing the error:

```
 images = np.vstack([x])
 classes = model.predict_classes(images, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: Maybe try `model.predict(images)`

Comment: The `Sequential` class doesn't have the `predict_classes` method. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict_classes` method is from an old version of keras (before version 2 so 2017 and older) and was removed since.

you can get the probabilities of your classes with `model.predict` and get your classes from there.

Comment: here is where I found the reference to predict_classes in the keras code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/4fa7e5d454dd4f3f33f1d756a2a8659f2e789141/keras/models.py